# Avoid redirect htaccess redirect for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We currently use a redirect on our main domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) to automatically go to the main directory ([www.example.com/main](http://www.example.com/main)) when not one of the few allowed other directories using the below code;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(logos|press|main)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great but we are now seeing an issue though when trying to use a subdomain (dev.example.com) will automatically reroute to [www.example.com/main](http://www.example.com/main).

How would I maintain the normal redirect we do on our main page but allow for the dev.example.com subdomain to also be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I assume that both hosts ("main domain" and "subdomain") are served from the same http server? If so you obviously need a condition that takes care that your redirection rule only gets applied if a specific host is requested ("www.example.com"):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(logos|press|main)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /main{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! It looks to be working just as intended. And just to ensure I understand it correctly, this is setup so that any subdomain/sub with directories will be fine be it `xxx.example.com` or `xxx.example.com/yyy` but once its loaded as `www.example.com` (which I assume `https://example.com` automatically loads as www) , it will then check to see if the directory then is either logos/press/main and allow anything with those, otherwise will default to main and any subdirs after that. Think I got it but does that sound about right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would suggest you simply try to understand what is actually coded there. This forward interpretation is much easier to follow: This is a simple redirection rule into the `/main` folder which will get applied to all requests, _except_ if one of the two conditions is _not_ fulfilled: 1. the requests host name must be either "www.example.com" or "example.com" (that is _not_ the same) and the requested path does _not_ start with the folder "logos", "press" or "main".

Comment: In general you should never just copy stuff you found or were given somewhere on the internet. You need to _understand_ what is coded there. So if something is not obvious for you, then go, take a look into the documentation and understand how things actually work _before_ accepting them. That way you learn, you get better and better every single day.